# output of query result shows more rows then it should do

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Now as you can see the query I have used above if a keyword is entered is this:

```
SELECT * FROM Question WHERE QuestionContent LIKE '%$each%';
```

Now I have 25 rows in the database where it contains the keyword "Question", so if I enter in keyword "Question" in search box, I get 25 rows displayed in the output which is correct.

The problem is that I need to inner join other table into the query as in future I will need to be able to look at rows from fields in other tables, so I changed the query to this below:

```
SELECT * FROM Answer a               
INNER JOIN Question q ON a.QuestionId = q.QuestionId
                 JOIN  Reply r ON q.ReplyId = r.ReplyId
                 WHERE QuestionContent LIKE '%$each%';
```

Now if I search for the word "Question" again, I end up getting 125 rows displayed in the result, not 25. Why is it doing this and does anybody know how this can be fixed?

Below is Question Table fields:

```
QuestionId, QuestionContent, ReplyId
```

Below is Answer Table fields:

```
QuestionId, Answer
```

Below is Reply Table fields:

```
ReplyId, ReplyType
```

Comment: You need to either convert your `JOIN` of `Reply` to an `INNER JOIN` or make it a subquery of some sort. I'd offer a suggestion of how to do the latter, but you didn't provide any criteria to use (and absolutely no sample data or schema) in order to do so.

Comment: Also, you're missing a large chunk of code, but all of it (except the SQL portion) is totally unrelated to your question. (All of the output that creates the table, for instance, is totally irrelevant.) You can (and should) edit to remove it to clarify your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's gonna be hard to give a good answer with the information given, but I'm guessing there are multiple answers per question and multiple replies per question.

You're gonna have to think about how you want your data queried, if you really want one row per question matched, then you need to `GROUP BY` the `QuestionId` which will mean getting rid of the `SELECT *`.

There's no "fix" to this, you will need to engineer a solution that best fits how the data is searched.

But adding a `GROUP BY` to your sql query will be a good start.

Also please tell me `$each` is being escaped with [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)

Comment: Figured it out, I will do the mysql real escape b4 I forget. upvote, best answer

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple answers per question (as I would imagine you will have), you'll get back the same question for each answer. You could use `GROUP BY`, or `SELECT DISTINCT` for this query as it is at the moment, but that will be a problem when you want stuff from each answer.

Comment: I am only search for a question, I won't be searching for an answer or anything like that, the field "Answer" would just be associated with the question in the same row, so could I try GROUP BY if I am only searching for question using the WHERE clause as im doing now?

Comment: If you add `GROUP BY QuestionId` at the end of your query, you'll get one row per question. This doesn't solve the issue of accessing multiple answers/replies per question though, if it's relevant.

Comment: Yeah I found out what happened when I grouped it bu Question Id, what should I Group it by?